# How to highlight track in KML on hover with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector, kml

I have KML layer with multiple tracks and I would like to highlight them individually on mouse hover. I tried to implement this like in the [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html) found in OpenLayers examples, but couldn't get it work.

In the [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html) there is following code that adds polygon as feature. In my case, how do I add KML-tracks as feature so that I can highlight them with SelectFeature?

```
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT(
        "POLYGON((28.828125 0.3515625, 132.1875 -13.0078125, -1.40625 -59.4140625, 28.828125 0.3515625))"
    )
);
vectors.addFeatures([feature]);
```

You can find simplified version of my index.html and KML file here: https://gist.github.com/1379118

Answer (score 3):

Your code has no SelectFeature handlers.

Look at the source code of the sample you linked to, there are 2 controls, one that acts on a "highlight" (or a "hover") and the other on a select/click.  You need to create handlers like that and add your vector layer to it.

...from the sample file

```
var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature...
...
var selectCtrl = ...
```

Comment: That sample was supposed to only show the starting point where to add highlighting feature. I updated the sample with SelectFeatures included. It doesn't yet work because I should also addFeatures, but don't know how to exactly do it.

Comment: Vector layer has the function to addFeature.  http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.addFeatures

Comment: See this example on how the features are created and added to the map.  Ignore the rotating part if it's not applicable.  http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/rotate-features.html